# how to clear all cells from google spreadsheet (and change last edited column)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

For a script I build I have a form that needs "cleaning" each "n time", removing all responses and also the spreadsheet it is bound to needs to be cleared.

While clearing it is seemingly simple (`form` and `sheet` refer the form and the corresponding sheet, it is executed from the scope of the spreadsheet).

```
form.deleteAllResponses();
var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
range.clearContent();
```

This doesn't seem to work: it creates side effects. The form seems to wish to "start over" and just adds a new set of columns representing the answers, not using the already existing columns, ie with 4 answers being in column A to D, the next submission after cleaning will be in column E to H.

Now a change would be

```
form.deleteAllResponses();
sheet.clear();
```

However this creates a "similar" problem: the form once agains creates a new set of columns to use. *after* the last column of the sheet.

So how can I tell the form to "just start reusing the first columns" - or in other words: how can I tell the spreadsheet that "after cleaning the last edited column is A"?

Comment: Check your range syntax. It should be `sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn())`

Comment: @BrianBennett oops, thanks for spotting that bug - little to do with the actual problem though

Comment: Just the first thing I noticed. Try the answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Forms indexes which row is the "active" row for the form submission. You want to make sure to delete the entire row, not just clear the contents. This should do it:

```js
function clearAll() {
  var form = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getFormUrl();
  FormApp.openByUrl(form).deleteAllResponses();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("formData");
  sheet.deleteRows(2, sheet.getLastRow());
}
```